# Industry term for when an app pre-fills information and remembers settings?

Tags: terminology

Is there a UX industry term for the system behavior where a user's information and preferences (like name or language) is carried across pages to personalize the experience of using the site?

Answer (score 1):

If your web site / application controls this system behavior, it is called *personalization*. If user controls it, it is called *customization*.

More on this you can find for instance here:

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/customization-personalization/

https://uxplanet.org/the-difference-between-customization-and-personalization-624ddd70b163